# jboss/eap docker container error from jgroups stack

Tags: docker, jboss-eap-7, jgroups

While running the docker container using "registry.redhat.io/jboss-eap-7/eap73-openjdk8-openshift-rhel7" base image getting the following error. For testing purpose this is executed as a standalone docker container(using docker runtime) under RHEL7.4

Docker CMD

CMD ["/opt/eap/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "***-standalone.xml", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]

Docker RUN

docker run -p 8002:8002 -p 8003:8003 -t jboss/app:latest

**Error**

*07:52:31,747 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
("channel" => "ee")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.jgroups.channel.ee" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.Exception: events [FIND_INITIAL_MBRS FIND_MBRS] are required by GMS, but not provided by any of the protocols below it*

This is the jgroups stack present inside the ***standalone.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:7.0">
                <channels default="ee">
                    <channel name="ee" stack="udp"/>
                </channels>
                <stacks>
                    <stack name="tcp">
                        <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                        <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                        <protocol type="FD_SOCK"/>
                        <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                        <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                        <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                        <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                        <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                        <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                        <protocol type="MFC"/>
                        <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
                    </stack>
                    <stack name="udp">
                        <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>
                        <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                        <protocol type="FD_SOCK"/>
                        <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                        <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                        <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                        <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                        <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                        <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                        <protocol type="UFC"/>
                        <protocol type="MFC"/>
                        <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
                    </stack>
                </stacks>
            </subsystem>
```

Regards,

Balu

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I removed `<protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>` and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @LucasBasquerotto. Will check this out.

Comment: removing pbcast.GMS can be solution. Another solution can be reordering protocols and/or stacks. My problem was TCPPING an last place. After I order it to first place GMS is  started too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your udp protocol list isn't complete. My snippet is from wildfly26.1.2 but Ithin PING protocol was the missing.

The order is serious too! See your original standalone-ha.xml!

```
<stacks>
            <stack name="udp">
                <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>
                <protocol type="PING"/>
                <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="UFC"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
            </stack>
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <socket-protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
                <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
            </stack>
        </stacks>
```